# DataTables - Sort by column 10 then by column 9 on initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

In my datatables I can sort by a specific column on initialization by using the code below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var dataTable = $('#contracts-datatable').DataTable({
   bLengthChange: false,
   "pageLength": 10,
   "pagingType": "simple",
   "order": [[ 9, "asc" ]], // <<--- Sorting by column 9
```

What I'd like to do is sort by column 10 first then sort the data by column 9.

On my website when I sort like this it arranges data more efficiently - how can I run this on initialization of my dataTables?

I tried..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var dataTable = $('#contracts-datatable').DataTable({
   bLengthChange: false,
   "pageLength": 10,
   "pagingType": "simple",
   "order": [[ 10, "asc" ], [ 9, "asc"]],
```

http://mobilereactor.co.uk/shop/mobile-phones/apple-iphone-5c-8gb-white-deals/

But it doesn't work. These are also hidden columns if that makes any difference.

What should happen with this column sort is I should end up with all the initial cost (free) mobiles on the first page and they should be ordered by their monthly price ascending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  "order": [[ 10, 'asc' ], [9, 'asc' ]]

```
           "order": [[ 10, 'asc' ], [9, 'asc' ]]
```

Codepen URL for reference - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/yJOaLv

Comment: that just orders by column 9 also

Comment: in my exapmple ..i am doing asc column position first  i.e Accountant and then column age ....if you see position got sorted asc in alphabetical order and age got sorted asc for column - Accountant

Comment: same kinda thing i'm trying to do ordering by hidden columns, by monthly price then by initial cost but it doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: did you try order sequence ? to fix sort type of those columns 10 and 9 to asc only

Comment: $('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "orderSequence": [ "asc" ], "targets": [ 10 ] },
     { "orderSequence": [ "asc" ], "targets": [ 9 ] }
  ]
} );

Comment: Did this change   "order": [[ 10, 'asc' ], [9, 'asc' ]] give close to your expected result?

Comment: I have edited the question - no it isn't doing what I expected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114487/discussion-between-naga-sai-a-and-scott).

Comment: One other option is to apply sorting separately i.e 
dataTable.order( [[ 9, 'asc' ])
    .draw();
after giving initial ordering as order( [[ 10, 'asc' ]) then followed by above 2 lines of code..which might work

Comment: where do i put the dataTable.order( [[ 9, "asc" ]).draw();

Comment: After completion of initial initialization 
var dataTable = $('#contracts-datatable').DataTable({
   bLengthChange: false,
   "pageLength": 10,
   "pagingType": "simple",
   "order": [[ 10, "asc" ]]});
dataTable.order([[9,"as"]).draw();

Comment: not working can you update your answer with possible solutions maybe I'm getting the syntax wrong

Comment: it is a syntax error which i have corrected...in the codepen url -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/OXNRxm   test it once ..hope it works this time

Comment: I guess even when you tried with [[ 10, 'asc' ], [9, 'asc' ]] has a syntax error...thats why it seems it didnt work...i have corrected the syntax with that  option.Can you try once - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/OXNRxm

Comment: link to jq file - im using two datatables view-source:http://mobilereactor.co.uk/wp-content/themes/wootique-child/js/iactivities.js?ver=12:49:43

Comment: guess what worked for me in the end lol ```"order": [[ 9, "asc" ], [ 10, "asc" ]],```

Comment: Oh ..I am sure multi mapping syntax is that ..but now I got to know that should be given in order :)... Hope my answer helped you..if so can you mark it answered :)